# Make command is usable for Objective-C project?

Tags: objective-c, makefile

I'm looking for an Objective-C open source project with Makefile, but I didn't find anything like that. I need that to test my clang static analyser project. Is it possible to make an Objective-C project?

Comment: Can you link an open source project with makefile?

Comment: Here's one I wrote: https://github.com/counsyl/scanstream/blob/master/Makefile  But this is very simple, using `xcodebuild`. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Thanks, I just need to check some Objective-C projects with my checkers. It works on Ubuntu but I need to run it on Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `make` for Objective C is certainly possible, and quite convenient.

Example is here: https://github.com/wkoszek/objc_edu/blob/master/makefile